# How to apply numpy matrix operations on first two dimensions of 3D array

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

I have a 3D numpy array which I am using to represent a tuple of (square) matrices, and I'd like to perform a matrix operation on each of those matrices, corresponding to the first two dimensions of the array.  For instance, if my list of matrices is [A,B,C] I would like to compute [A'A,B'B,C'C] where ' denotes the conjugate transpose.

The following code kinda sorta does what I'm looking for:

```
foo=np.array([[[1,1],[0,1]],[[0,1],[0,0]],[[3,0],[0,-2]]])
[np.matrix(j).H*np.matrix(j) for j in foo]
```

But I'd like to do this using vectorized operations instead of list comprehension.

Comment: If the batch dimension was first (outer most) you could use `np.matmul`. No need to use `np.matrix`.  Or look at `np.einsum`

Comment: And `np.conj` can be used on a `ndarray`; again you don't need `np.matrix`.

Comment: Thanks, that did what I needed!